# Matlab to workspace and rms value different

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a very simple circuit in matlab.
[image]

There is a voltage source of 100 V peak. Both resistance if of 100 ohm.
If I see the voltage in `display` box, it shows `36.476 V`

But in the `TESTV` matrix it shows `25.1761` V

Why is it different?

This is the dialog properties of `TESTV`
[image: testv]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the decimation as 1

See this link 
[Matlab help link](http://www.mathworks.in/help/simulink/slref/toworkspace.html)

`For example, suppose you have a simulation where the start time is 0, the Limit data points to last is 100, the Decimation is 1, and the Sample time is 0.5. The To Workspace block collects a maximum of 100 points, at time values of 0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, ..., seconds. Specifying a Decimation value of 1 directs the block to write data at each step.`

I took the **decimation as 1** and I got same values in workspace and in matrix

[image: testv]

Answer (score 1):

The `Display box` probably show the value from a different time step. I would try changing the `configuration parameters` and the step time values and the `simulation time`.

Answer (score 1):

In your "To Workspace" block you have a Decimation of 5. This means you are not logging data every time step. You are logging data only once every 5 time steps. Like m_power has noted, you may not be comparing values from same time step.